# Jquery call if div exists

Tags: html, exists

Im trying to call if div exists with the following code. 
Div 1 and 2 are recognized when tested, but it doesnt recognize div 3. 
Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('.3').length){
    alert("Div exists");
}else{
    alert("Div not exists");
}
</script> 
<div id="1">
<div class="2">
<div class="3">test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if it is solved, mark the selected answer.

Comment: Hey Sailes, you should make it a rule of thumb to never start a class or an id with a number :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code will work for .2/#1 either, since you are trying to access the elements even before they are available in DOM.

Wrap the JS code in jQuery ready event handler.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if($('.3').length){
            alert("Div exists");
    }else{
            alert("Div not exists");
    }
});
</script> 
<div id="1">
<div class="2">
<div class="3">test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried to find an example of this but a quick Google was fruitless I am pretty sure you are not supposed to use numbers as the start of CSS class names.

try adding firstly the document ready statement and change 1 :one and 2:two and so on see if this bears any fruit.